# What is the pythonic way to count the leading spaces in a string?

Tags: python

I know I can count the leading spaces in a string with this:

```
>>> a = "   foo bar baz qua   \n"
>>> print "Leading spaces", len(a) - len(a.lstrip())
Leading spaces 3
>>>
```

But is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: Looks pretty pythonic to me already.

Comment: Unpleasant -- but different -- way: `a.count(" ", 0, a.index(a.split(None, 1)[0]))`

Comment: Bear in mind that lstrip will remove tabs and other whitespace characters as well as spaces.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Your way is pythonic but incorrect, it will also count other whitespace chars, to count only spaces be explicit `a.lstrip(' ')`. Compare

```py
a = "   \r\t\n\tfoo bar baz qua   \n"
print("Leading spaces", len(a) - len(a.lstrip()))
```

```
>>> Leading spaces 7
```

and

```py
print("Leading spaces", len(a) - len(a.lstrip(' '))
```

```
>>> Leading spaces 3
```

Answer (score 26):

You could use `itertools.takewhile`

```
sum( 1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(str.isspace,a) )
```

And demonstrating that it gives the same result as your code:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = "    leading spaces"
>>> print sum( 1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(str.isspace,a) )
4
>>> print "Leading spaces", len(a) - len(a.lstrip())
Leading spaces 4
```

I'm not sure whether this code is actually *better* than your original solution.  It has the advantage that it doesn't create more temporary strings, but that's pretty minor (unless the strings are really big).  I don't find either version to be immediately clear about that line of code does, so I would definitely wrap it in a nicely named function if you plan on using it more than once (with appropriate comments in either case).

Comment: I was trying to figure out exactly this, only without itertools.  I really need to learn itertools...

Comment: @sr2222 -- Sometimes I think `itertools` is over used, (maybe because it's so useful for so many things).  It's a good thing to know.

Comment: @holdenweb -- I'm glad you said something.  I recently learned that what I posted here is actually incorrect, but couldn't find the post.  While that optimization *is* technically possible, I think that real-world tests showed that it really didn't matter.  In *most* cases, the data does actually get copied.

Comment: On my system, (Python 2.7.10 32 bit running on Windows), lstrip() is 3.5x as fast as itertools.

Comment: @ChaimG -- I _bet_ that we _could_ construct some strings for which that isn't the case (e.g. if the string is _really_ long and only has one or two leading spaces).  For many common cases however, I agree that `lstrip` will be much faster.

Comment: @mgilson -- Correct. With the string: `a = ' ' + 'a'*100000000`, itertools is 67k times faster. I wonder why? Is it because lstrip() creates a copy of the string?

Comment: @ChaimG -- that's exactly why :-).  At one point, I assumed that `lstrip()` wouldn't create a new string -- Immutability _should_ make that possible.  However, I made that statement on a google mailing list once and was corrected by Alex Martelli IIRC :-).  I'm not sure why they _don't_ re-use the old string, but it might be because in a lot of cases that would prevent a large string from getting deallocated.

Answer (score 18):

Just for variety, you could theoretically use regex. It's a little shorter, and looks nicer than the double call to `len()`.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "   foo bar baz qua   \n"
>>> re.search('\S', a).start() # index of the first non-whitespace char
3
```

Or alternatively:

```
>>> re.search('[^ ]', a).start() # index of the first non-space char
3
```

But I don't recommend this; according to a quick test I did, it's much less efficient than `len(a)-len(lstrip(a))`.

Answer (score 6):

I recently had a similar task of counting indents, because of which I wanted to count tab as four spaces:

```
def indent(string: str):
    return sum(4 if char is '\t' else 1 for char in string[:-len(string.lstrip())])
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `next` and `enumerate`:

```
next((i for i, c in enumerate(a) if c != ' '), len(a))
```

For any whitespace:

```
next((i for i, c in enumerate(a) if not c.isspace()), len(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks... great to me. Usually I answer "Is X Pythonic?" questions with some functional magic, but I don't feel that approach is appropriate for string manipulation.

If there were a built-in to *only* return the leading spaces, and the take the `len()` of that, I'd say go for it- but AFAIK there isn't, and `re` and other solutions are absolutely overkill.

Comment: I agree it's overkill `len(re.split("\S", a, 1)[0])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression:

```py
def count_leading_space(s): 
    match = re.search(r"^\s*", s) 
    return 0 if not match else match.end()

In [17]: count_leading_space("    asd fjk gl")                                  
Out[17]: 4

In [18]: count_leading_space(" asd fjk gl")                                     
Out[18]: 1

In [19]: count_leading_space("asd fjk gl")                                      
Out[19]: 0
```

Comment: This counts other whitespace chars (like tabs) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it for the sake of completeness. Probably useless as unlikely faster or shorter than other answers.

```
import re
a = "   foo bar baz qua   \n"
print(len(re.split("\S", a, 1)[0]))
```

A good property of that syntax is that it literally gives you the prefix.