# Getting a Python function's source code without the definition lines

Tags: python, function

Using the `inspect.getsourcelines` function, I have been able to get a Python function's source code like this:

```
import inspect    

def some_decorator(x):
    return x

@some_decorator
def foo():
    print("bar")

print(inspect.getsourcelines(foo)[0])
```

This code will correctly output the source lines of the function as a list:

```
['@some_decorator\n', 'def foo():\n', '    print("bar")\n']
```

However, I only want the code *inside* the function, not the entire function declaration.  So I only want this output (noting also the correct indentation):

```
['print("bar")\n']
```

I have attempted to do this using a slice and a `strip` to remove the first two lines and then remove indentation, but this wouldn't work with many functions and I have to believe there's a better way.

Does the `inspect` module, or another module which I can `pip install`, have this functionality?

Comment: It should be simple by: using the amount of whitespace in the first line as base and then finding the first line which has *more* whitespace than that; that's the start of your function body. Optionally trim the amount of starting whitespace of that first body line from all following lines. – Do you have an example of a function where "that wouldn't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import inspect
from itertools import dropwhile


def get_function_body(func):
    source_lines = inspect.getsourcelines(func)[0]
    source_lines = dropwhile(lambda x: x.startswith('@'), source_lines)
    def_line = next(source_lines).strip()
    if def_line.startswith('def ') and def_line.endswith(':'):
        # Handle functions that are not one-liners  
        first_line = next(source_lines)
        # Find the indentation of the first line    
        indentation = len(first_line) - len(first_line.lstrip())
        return ''.join([first_line[indentation:]] + [line[indentation:] for line in source_lines])
    else:
        # Handle single line functions
        return def_line.rsplit(':')[-1].strip()
```

**Demo:**

```
def some_decorator(x):
    return x


@some_decorator
def foo():
    print("bar")


def func():
    def inner(a, b='a:b'):
        print (100)
        a = c + d
        print ('woof!')
        def inner_inner():
            print (200)
            print ('spam!')
    return inner

def func_one_liner(): print (200); print (a, b, c)

print (get_function_body(foo))
print (get_function_body(func()))
print (get_function_body(func_one_liner))

func_one_liner = some_decorator(func_one_liner)
print (get_function_body(func_one_liner))
```

**Output:**

```
print("bar")

print (100)
a = c + d
print ('woof!')
def inner_inner():
    print (200)
    print ('spam!')

print (200); print (a, b, c)
print (200); print (a, b, c)
```

---

**Update:**

To handle `async` and functions with multiline argument signature `get_function_body` should be updated to:

```
import inspect
import re
from itertools import dropwhile


def get_function_body(func):
    print()
    print("{func.__name__}'s body:".format(func=func))
    source_lines = inspect.getsourcelines(func)[0]
    source_lines = dropwhile(lambda x: x.startswith('@'), source_lines)
    source = ''.join(source_lines)
    pattern = re.compile(r'(async\s+)?def\s+\w+\s*\(.*?\)\s*:\s*(.*)', flags=re.S)
    lines = pattern.search(source).group(2).splitlines()
    if len(lines) == 1:
        return lines[0]
    else:
        indentation = len(lines[1]) - len(lines[1].lstrip())
        return '\n'.join([lines[0]] + [line[indentation:] for line in lines[1:]])
```

**Demo:**

```
def some_decorator(x):
    return x


@some_decorator
def foo():
    print("bar")


def func():
    def inner(a, b='a:b'):
        print (100)
        a = c + d
        print ('woof!')
        def inner_inner():
            print (200)
            print ('spam!')
    return inner


def func_one_liner(): print (200); print (a, b, c)
async def async_func_one_liner(): print (200); print (a, b, c)


def multi_line_1(
    a=10,
    b=100): print (100); print (200)


def multi_line_2(
    a=10,
    b=100
    ): print (100); print (200)


def multi_line_3(
    a=10,
    b=100
    ):
    print (100 + '\n')
    print (200)

async def multi_line_4(
    a=10,
    b=100
    ):
    print (100 + '\n')
    print (200)

async def multi_line_5(
    a=10,
    b=100
    ): print (100); print (200)

def func_annotate(
    a: 'x', b: 5 + 6, c: list
    ) -> max(2, 9): print (100); print (200)


print (get_function_body(foo))
print (get_function_body(func()))
print (get_function_body(func_one_liner))
print (get_function_body(async_func_one_liner))

func_one_liner = some_decorator(func_one_liner)
print (get_function_body(func_one_liner))


@some_decorator
@some_decorator
def foo():
    print("bar")

print (get_function_body(foo))
print (get_function_body(multi_line_1))
print (get_function_body(multi_line_2))
print (get_function_body(multi_line_3))
print (get_function_body(multi_line_4))
print (get_function_body(multi_line_5))
print (get_function_body(func_annotate))
```

**Output:**

```
foo's body:
print("bar")

inner's body:
print (100)
a = c + d
print ('woof!')
def inner_inner():
    print (200)
    print ('spam!')

func_one_liner's body:
print (200); print (a, b, c)

async_func_one_liner's body:
print (200); print (a, b, c)

func_one_liner's body:
print (200); print (a, b, c)

foo's body:
print("bar")

multi_line_1's body:
print (100); print (200)

multi_line_2's body:
print (100); print (200)

multi_line_3's body:
print (100 + '\n')
print (200)

multi_line_4's body:
print (100 + '\n')
print (200)

multi_line_5's body:
print (100); print (200)

func_annotate's body:
print (100); print (200)
```

Comment: This works correctly even with one-liner functions! I have to say that I think this is the best, least-"hacky" answer. Thanks also for introducting me to `itertools.dropwhile`.

Comment: This fails for `async def` functions and multi-line function signatures.

Comment: If you want to support yet another variant: single-line definitions using type hints, e.g. `def foo(bar:tuple=()) -> dict: print(bar)`. ;)

Comment: The two solutions above break if the definition takes more than one line **and** annotations are used (since annotations introduce extra ":"). I'll post, below, a `get_function_body` function that works in this case too.

Answer (score 5):

The two solutions in the accepted answer break if the definition takes more than one line **and** annotations are used (since annotations introduce extra ":"). In the following I take care of that case too (but not the async case contained in the accepted answer's second function.

```py
import inspect
from itertools import dropwhile


def get_function_body(func):
    source_lines = inspect.getsourcelines(func)[0]
    source_lines = dropwhile(lambda x: x.startswith('@'), source_lines)
    line = next(source_lines).strip()
    if not line.startswith('def '):
        return line.rsplit(':')[-1].strip()
    elif not line.endswith(':'):
        for line in source_lines:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.endswith(':'):
                break
    # Handle functions that are not one-liners  
    first_line = next(source_lines)
    # Find the indentation of the first line    
    indentation = len(first_line) - len(first_line.lstrip())
    return ''.join([first_line[indentation:]] + [line[indentation:] for line in source_lines])
```

For example, applied to:

```py
# A pre comment
def f(a, b: str, c='hello', 
      d: float=0.0, *args, **kwargs) -> str:
    """The docs"""
    return f"{c} {b}: {a + d}"

print(get_function_body(f))
```

I get

```
"""The docs"""
return f"{c} {b}: {a + d}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find that the code you want all have blank before, so you can
try this

```
print filter(lambda x:x.startswith(' '), inspect.getsourcelines(foo)[0])
```

Comment: That's a great way of doing it. I'm on Python 3, so I had to adapt it a little bit, but otherwise that's fantastic. Thank you! Here's the Python 3 version for anybody else: `print(list(filter(lambda x:x.startswith(' '), inspect.getsourcelines(foo)[0])))`

Comment: Note that this will not work if the definition itself is indented already, or if code is indented via tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re` to handle `def` and `async def`:

```
def_regexp = r"^(\s*)(?:async\s+)?def foobar\s*?\:"
def get_func_code(func):
  lines = inspect.getsourcelines(foo)[0]
  for idx in range(len(lines)):  # in py2.X, use range
      def_match = re.match(line, def_regexp)
      if def_match:
          withespace_len = len(def_match.group(1))  # detect leading whitespace
          return [sline[whitespace_len:] for sline in lines[idx+1:]]
```

Note that this will *not* handle single-line definitions. One would need to match opening and closing brackets after the def and contained colons (to avoid tuples and type hints.)

---

Original Version:

Just look for the first line containing a `def` statement.

```
def get_func_code(func):
  lines = inspect.getsourcelines(foo)[0]
  for idx in range(len(lines)):  # in py2.X, use range
      if line.lstrip().startswith('def %s' % func.__name__) or\
         line.lstrip().startswith('async def %s' % func.__name__):  # actually should check for `r"^async\s+def\s+%s" % func.__name__` via re
          withespace_len = len(line.split('def'), 1)[0]  # detect leading whitespace
          return [sline[whitespace_len:] for sline in lines[idx+1:]]
```

This should safely handle both tab and space indentation, even in mixed cases.

Comment: Fails for `async def` functions.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, added a check for that as well (and had fun reading the PEP ^^).

Comment: I am contractually obliged to point out that it's *possible* for there to be multiple spaces between `async` and `def`...

Comment: @deceze Already added a note on that. ;) (If anybody knows a nicer solution than `re`, speak up.)

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach of @Daoctor, with a couple of improvements:

1. I combined it with the [following recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13649013/4334041) to get the indentation of each line in a rather agnostic way.
2. We have to be careful that the functions can be nested and are therefore not always start at column 0 of the line. We can work around that, because we can also determine the indentation of the first line of the function.
3. Similarly, we can cut that extra-indentation for all lines of the body.

Here is the function (tested):

```
    def get_function_body(func):
        """
        Get the body of a function
        """
        def indentation(s):
            "Get the indentation (spaces of a line)"
            return len(s) - len(s.lstrip())

        source = inspect.getsourcelines(func)[0]
        # print(source)
        # get the indentation of the first line
        line_0 = source[0]
        ind_0 = indentation(line_0)
        body = []
        for line in source[1:]:
            ind = indentation(line)
            if ind > ind_0:
                # append to the body (minus the extra indentation)
                body.append(line[ind_0:])
        return ''.join(body)
```