# What's the quickest way to find the number of spaces that begin a string in Python?

Tags: python, text-parsing

What's the quickest way to find the number of spaces that begin a string? I'm wanting this to calculate things like how nested my space-indents are (when text parsing).

E.g.

```
s="     There are five spaces"
num=num_start_spaces(s) #it equals five
```

I probably wouldn't have asked this, but I noticed I didn't find a quick reference for it anywhere (so, I thought I'd do my own Q/A; if you have another way, feel free to contribute!).

Comment: `len(s.split(" ")[0])+1`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative answer:

```
def countspaces(x):
    for i, j in enumerate(x):
        if j != ' ':
            return i

s="     There are five spaces"

countspaces(s)  # 5
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use `str.lstrip()` method and take the difference of the lengths of both strings, which will be the number of spaces that begin the string.

```
def num_start_spaces(text):
    return len(text)-len(text.lstrip(" "))

print(num_start_spaces("        spaces"))
```

The above prints "8 spaces".

Edit: I enhanced this answer above using info from the duplicate question.

However, for the task at hand, I think doing this alone in the context stated is going to be a little tedious and have a lot of overhead. Before you do any text parsing, you'll probably want to use it to make a list of the indents per line (and then when you iterate through the lines, you'll have that for quick reference):

```
lines=myString.split("\n") #lines is the lines of the text we're parsing
indents=[] #Values are the number of indents on the line.
for line in lines:
    spaces=num_start_spaces(line)
    if spaces%4!=0:
        raise ValueError("The spaces on line "+str(len(indents))+" are not zero or a multiple of four:", spaces)
    indents.append(spaces/4)

i=0
while i<len(lines):
    #Do text parsing here (and use indents for reference). We're in a while loop so we can reference lines before and after more easily than in a for loop.
    i+=1
```

Comment: How is this any different (or enhanced) than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13649013/5858851) to the [exact duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648813/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-count-the-leading-spaces-in-a-string) which you have not attributed?

Comment: It's not. I just didn't find that when I searched (I'm one of the people who upvoted the comment about the duplicate, btw). @pault

Comment: What I meant was that after the duplicate was discovered, I used what I saw there to enhance my answer (not to make it better than that one).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. In my opinion, you should probably just delete this question. But if you want to keep it, at least acknowledge the other answer in your post.

Comment: I upvoted the other answer. I'll leave the question undeleted to make it easier to find (and because I added something to my answer directed at the unique aspect of the question).