# How to create a condition to copy strings if value starts from a certain point in the txt file line

Tags: python, substring, etl

I want to prepare a TXT file, turn it into a table. I can already remove headers and lines with useless data with the command below.

```
bad_words = ['ROCKET LTDA', 'PERIODO', 'CONTAS ANALITICO', 'Página']

with open('teste.txt') as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

The problem is that, I developed a logic that I cannot execute, I intend to check all the lines of the TXT. If the line information starts at position 8, I turn it into a column, if I start at 15 in another column, and so on. The logic would be, if on any given line you start to have some string in position 8, you would copy the next 20 characters and translate it into the description within the column of primary accounts. If the strings started at position 15, it would copy the next 20 strings and do the same process as the previous one, it would be a secondary account column.

The base txt file:

[image: The base txt file]

I want to transform the txt data into a column, but first I need to create the slice condition.

[image: I want to transform the txt data into a column, but first I need to create the slice condition.]

I would like to use the slice and "capture" strings according to the position on the line, I have a little difficulty in creating the conference condition.

Comment: when you say position in the line are you saying position 8 is line 8 or word 8 within a line?
if its line 8, you can keep count of line number outside of your for loop and update each time you iterate,  If it is word length you can probably call split on the line and iterate through the words while counting or enumerating them.  best of luck

Comment: if you load your base txt file as just txt we can copy and paste it to test and show you results as opposed to typing the picture you sent ;)

Comment: It is position 8 on the line. Within the line, if the first word starts at position 8, I will soon know that it is the data I need, if I meet the condition I will use the slice and copy the 20 characters after the eighth position. line [8:28].
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1uvRwaAPsshbsDdRoWqN89fgkHpxTeq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: oh, well if by position 8 on the line you mean there are 8 spaces  you can count the spaces to verify you are in a position then capture the split line

Comment: You can use `if line.startswith(" "*15):` to test the line indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Count the leading spaces, using one of the solutions in [What is the pythonic way to count the leading spaces in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648813/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-count-the-leading-spaces-in-a-string).

Then you can use this in conditions.

```
spaces = len(line) - len(line.lstrip(" "))
if spaces == 0:
    # process main header
elif spaces == 8:
    # process secondary header
elif spaces == 9:
    # process tertiary header
# and so on
```